# php inserting last inserted values to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have my login table in mysql is like this

```
id
fname
lname
email
contactno
userid
password
acctype
status
```

Now my form is like this

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="registerform.php">
  <table id="new-account" class="create-an-account" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
    <tr>
      <td width="45%">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:230px;"  name="Firstname" id="Firstname" /></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="45%">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:230px;"  name="LastName" id="LastName" />                      
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="">Account Type</label>
          <select class="select" name="at" id="ValidSelection" style="width:245px;" >
            <option value="0">Select Account Type</option>
            <option value="agent">agent</option>
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
          </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="">Email Id:</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="ValidEmail" style="width:230px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="">Contact Number</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="contact" id="ValidNumber" style="width:230px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for=""><strong>Choose Your Login Id:</strong></label>
      <input type="text" style="width:230px;"  name="LoginId" id="LoginId"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for=""><strong>Password: <br /></strong></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="password" style="width:230px;"  name="Password" id="ValidPassword"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="">Confirm Password:</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <input type="password" style="width:230px;"  name="ConfirmPassword" id="ValidConfirmPassword"
    />                      
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="signup" value="Create Account" style="margin-top:20px" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

and for insert data my php code is like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['signup'])) {
        mysql_query("insert into login (`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`contactno`,`userid`,`password`,`acctype`,`status`) values('".$_REQUEST['Firstname']."','".$_REQUEST['LastName']."','".$_REQUEST['email']."','".$_REQUEST['contact']."','".$_REQUEST['LoginId']."','".$pswd."','".$_REQUEST['at']."','active')");
    }
?>
```

Now here when I am reloading the page it is automatically inserting the last entered values to the database. So here can someone kindly tell me what is the issue here? Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your code is wide open for SQL injections!

Comment: If you reload the page after submitting a form, it will keep the POST data. Because it's set, the PHP page is resubmitting the data.

Comment: Your code is very weak and should not be used for any production environment, add extra check for all fields not just `signup`

Answer (score 2):

If you reload the page after submitting a form, it will keep the POST data. To solve this follow the below things :

1. You can redirect to some other page after inserting the data, use `header("location:new_page.php")`
2. You can unset REQUEST, use `unset($_REQUEST)` after insert

Answer (score 0):

after inserting the $_POST data use redirect to avoid this situation .
even you can redirect to same page like this :-

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  exit;
```